# Backbone.js: How do you call a View's "method" from outside the View's scope (e.g: inside a model's validation handler)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Basically, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
Person = Backbone.Model.extend({

   validate: { ... },

   initialize: function(){ 
      this.bind('error', ?......?); <== what do I put?
   },

   // I DON'T WANT TO CALL THIS ONE
   handleError: function(){ }

});


ViewOne = Backbone.View.extend({

   //I WANT TO CALL THIS ONE:
   handleError: function(model, error){ 
         //display inside segmented view using jQuery 
   };

});
```

I tried `options.view.handleError` but it doesn't work...

**My main purpose:** I want a specific View that created the model to handle the error, not have the model to globally handle it all. For example, I want View#1 to do an alert while I want View#2 to display in a div. I don't know if this is the right way of doing it. If not, I would be gladly accept your help.

Thank you.

---

**UPDATE:** here's my jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/jancarlo000/87mAk/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Backbone 0.5.2 it is recommended to drop bindAll in favor of third argument to bind if you need to pass the context.

```
ViewOne = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {            
        this.model.on('error', this.handleError, this);
    },
    handleError: function(model, error) { /* ... */ }
});
...
var person = new Person();
var viewone = new ViewOne({model : person});
```

General note here is that Models should never know about their Views. Only Views should subscribe to Model events.

Answer (score 3):

You have it backwards, the view should be binding to the model's events:

```
ViewOne = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'handleError');
        this.model.bind('error', this.handleError);
    },

    handleError: function(model, error) { /* ... */ }

});
```

Comment: it doesn't work for some reason. Mind if you could help me on my jsFiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/jancarlo000/87mAk/ ...it's a bit messy because I'm learning backbone.js still..

Comment: @Jan: You need to move the `this.model.bind` to where your view is getting the model (probably `runCode`) and replace `this.model` with the actual model (probably `j`).